# What would be a good way to pull the coefficients out of a string in Python?

Tags: python, symbolic-math

I'm trying to find a way to efficiently pull the coefficients out of a string that contains a symbolic polynomial and put them into a list, where the powers are the indeces. For example, a string

```
x^10+6x^4-5x^2+x-11
```

would be the list

```
[-11, 1, -5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I'm currently trying to learn regex to handle it, but my understanding of it isn't good enough to inspire confidence in its robustness (obviously, logic tells me otherwise). Can anyone set me on the right track to solving this problem?

Comment: How robust does the solution need to be to the reordering of the terms?  Should the program be able to handle `3x^2 - 5` and `-5 + 3x^2` or do your polynomials always have terms of descending powers?  My initial thought is that regular expressions are not the best choice and that something like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples) would be more suitable.

Comment: @ChrisP I would like the power to be the index, so that will take care of the robustness I believe. The biggest hurdle seems to be handling the 0th and 1st power coefficients. I haven't come up with a regex to handle those yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to parse the equation into a list of dictionaries with self-documenting keys. This approach is similar in spirit to Jmac's very fine answer.

```
eq = 'x^10+6x^4-5x^2+x-11'

patt = r'(?P<sign>[-+]?)(?P<coeff>\d*)(?P<x>x?)(?:\^(?P<exp>\d+))?'
rgx = re.compile(patt)

eq_parts = [m.groupdict() for m in rgx.finditer(eq)][0:-1]

for eqp in eq_parts:
    print eqp
```

Output:

```
{'x': 'x', 'coeff': '', 'exp': '10', 'sign': ''}
{'x': 'x', 'coeff': '6', 'exp': '4', 'sign': '+'}
{'x': 'x', 'coeff': '5', 'exp': '2', 'sign': '-'}
{'x': 'x', 'coeff': '', 'exp': None, 'sign': '+'}
{'x': '', 'coeff': '11', 'exp': None, 'sign': '-'}
```

Comment: This one is better than mine. I still haven't gotten used to naming each matching part.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern  `r'-?\d*x\^\d+|-?\d+x?|-?x'` should break apart the string.

For example:

```
import re

string = "x^10+6x^4-5x^2+x-11"

pattern = re.compile(r'-?\d*x\^\d+|-?\d+x?|-?x')
matches = pattern.findall(string)
# matches == ['x^10', '6x^4', '-5x^2', 'x', '-11']
```

The rest should be doable. I leave it as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That's magic. Do you mind if I ask you what materials you used to be able to get to the point of conjuring up such regex spells?

Comment: The official [re documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) helps. After looking at and  learning the special characters a lot about finding the expression is just trial and error.